# Jquery toggle doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery

I have this Jquery code:

```
 $('.item_bar_action_holder_drop a').click(function() {
            var item_bar = $('.item_bar_action_holder_actions');
            if(item_bar.is(':visible')) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
            item_bar.slideToggle('fast', function() {
            });
        });
```

The problem here is when I click many times the button the "active" class will set to a closed panel and its wrong. I cant understand why it happend.

Comment: you have got just 1 panel right?

Comment: can you show us your html and css too?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `item_bar` is being animated at the time, and don't queue anymore actions if it is:

```
$('.item_bar_action_holder_drop a').click(function() {
    var item_bar = $('.item_bar_action_holder_actions');
    if (item_bar.is(':animated')) {
        return;
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: @JohnMark perhaps you could provide a demo to show the exact behavior you are experiencing. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Basic slideToggle() example.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_slidetoggle)

I guess your active class's css is = display:block; and your item_bar's default css is display:none; if i am correct; you can use this way too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.item_bar_action_holder_drop a').click(function() {
      var item_bar = $('.item_bar_action_holder_actions');

      item_bar.removeClass('active');//removes class from all
      $(this).addClass('active');//adds class clicked one

      if( item_bar.is(':visible')) {//edited here !
        item_bar.slideToggle('fast',function() {
           $(this).removeClass('active');//removes class when animate complete
        });
      }
  });
  //if you want to show first panel when your document is ready
  $('.item_bar_action_holder_actions:first').show().addClass('active');
});
```

Note: You didnt show your html, so i am trying to guess your html.

Comment: its a good idea, but this code dont work properly. It will never open because the panel start closed

Comment: $('.item_bar_action_holder_drop a').click(function() {
                var item_bar = $('.item_bar_action_holder_actions');
                $(this).toggleClass('item_bar_action_clicked');
                item_bar.slideToggle('fast', function() {
    
                });
            });

This is my new code, very simple.. I am sorry guys, the problem was other jquery function with influence on the panel. Anyone know how can I see what javascript functions is "linked" to a button, for example
?